# iOS - Populate DB with java outside the app

Tags: java, iphone, database, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to write an application for iPhone/iPad which will use a database. This database is populated by a third party server so I would like to know what is the best method (SQLite,...) if I just want to drag/drop the database into my app. The database might be big so I don't think XML would be good.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Enable iTunes File Sharing for your app by adding `UIFileSharingEnabled` to it's Info.plist and setting it to `YES`.

Then write your app with a mock DB in place. Put the mock DB into the documents folder.

Every time you want to update your DB, simply connect your iPhone to your Mac, open iTunes, got to file sharing and drag-drop the new DB into the sharing window. This will overwrite the old DB without you needing to rebuild or reinstall.

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I'm looking for... the question is more: Is there a way to manipulate SQLite DB generated by CoreData with Java? The problem is the relationships between tables.